# Make a connection using an external IP address in Java

Tags: java, sockets, connection, port

I'm trying to build a chat program. I wrote the code and everything worked and still works great when I'm using my computer and connecting using 127.0.0.1. I also succeeded to connect successfully between my laptop and my computer, which run on the same router. (I used an internal IP address to do this, 10.0.0.3).

Now I'm trying to make a connection between my router and other routers. And to this I'm trying to connect to an external IP address. I do the port forwarding part through my router and I also made a static IP. When I run the code I always get a "connection refused error".

Here is the code:

MainServer.java:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MainServer {
  private ArrayList<Socket> sockets;
  public MainServer() {
    ServerSocket server_socket;
    try {
      server_socket = new ServerSocket(5005);
      sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();
      System.out.println("server is now running");
      while(true) {
        Socket socket = server_socket.accept();
        sockets.add(socket);
        try {
          PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
          writer.println("---you are connected to the server---\r\n");
          writer.flush();
        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        System.out.println("server connected to " + socket.getInetAddress());
        Reader reader = new Reader(socket);
        Thread thread = new Thread(reader);
        thread.start();
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainServer server = new MainServer();
  }
  class Reader implements Runnable {
    Socket socket;
    public Reader(Socket socket) {
      this.socket=socket;
    }
    public void run() {
      while(true) {
        try {
          InputStreamReader stream_reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream_reader);
          while(true) {
            String str = reader.readLine();
            if(str==null)
              continue;
            System.out.println("message from the client " + socket.getInetAddress() + ": " + str);
            send_back_message(str);
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    public void send_back_message(String str) {
      try {
        for(Socket send_to_socket: sockets) {
          PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(send_to_socket.getOutputStream());
          writer.println(send_to_socket.getInetAddress()+ ": " + str);
          writer.flush();
        }
      } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
  }
}
```

Client.java:

```
public Client() {
  frame = new JFrame();
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  chat = new JTextArea(20,40);
  chat.setEditable(false);
  JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(chat);
  text = new JTextField(32);
  JButton send = new JButton("Send");
  send.addActionListener(new SendButtonListener());
  panel.add(scroll);
  panel.add(text);
  panel.add(send);
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
  frame.setSize(500,500);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  try {
    socket = new Socket("77.126.189.65",5005);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  Thread thread = new Thread(new ClientReader());
  thread.start();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Client client = new Client();
}
class SendButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
      writer.println(text.getText());
      writer.flush();
      text.setText("");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
class ClientReader implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    try {
      InputStreamReader stream_reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream_reader);
      while(true) {
        String str = reader.readLine();
        if(str==null)
          continue;
        chat.setText(chat.getText() + str + "\r\n" );
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
}
```

I also tried [this tool](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/). When I run the MainServer file and try the tool, I get a positive answer. I also get a positive on my own Eclipse. When my MainServer makes a successful connection, it prints a message about it using these lines:

```
Socket socket = server_socket.accept();
System.out.println("server connected to " + socket.getInetAddress());
```

So every time I'm clicking the "check" button in the tool above, I get a message in my Eclipse console (system.out.println part):

> server connected to /69.163.149.200

Therefore I think the problem is probably not connected to the MainServer or the portforwading/firewall/static IP.

I also thought maybe the problem occurs because I'm trying connecting from my own router device to my own router. I will leave the MainServer file open for the next half hour so if someone can run the Client.java on his computer it will be helpful.

Comment: in your tests... both client and server are behind the same router?

Comment: yes i run the server and the client on the same eclipse same computer and same router

Comment: If you are still inside LAN (as i understand) you have to use internal IP. If you are on the same computer, you have to use 127.0.0.1

Comment: i dont realy understand what LAN is. i already used internal ip and it worked. the main point of the program is to connect between diffrent routers, so i use extenal ip. i trying to make a connection on my own computer only for checking if the program work when i use external ip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you trying to do is a bit weird but it is possible.

You just need to know if your router supports [NAT Loopback / NAT Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT-loopback) and activate it.

> **NAT-loopback**
>
> Also known as NAT-hairpinning or NAT-reflection. NAT-loopback is a
>   feature in many consumer routers which allows a user to connect to
>   its own public IP address from inside the LAN-network. This is
>   especially useful when a website (with domain) is hosted at that IP
>   address.

Comment: ok thanks im actually dont want it. but now i understand that i cant connect my router on default to itself and thats why the program doesnt worked

Comment: by the way how can i buy or get free a server which can run java files. (im looking for something similar to website hosting)

Comment: sorry... I don't know... i did a fast search in google an thousand appeared but i no experience in java hosting =(

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this without configuring your router appropriately.  Most routers do not allow (by default) incoming connections on their external (WAN) port.  If you want to allow this, you'll need to go into your router configuration and configure it to allow connections on the external IP for the specific port you are using.  Then, you'll have to configure the router to redirect that incoming connection from the external IP address/port to the internal IP address/port of your actual server.

This is frequently how online gamers set up servers in their own home.  It is also how many people connect to their own internal networks from the outside world.

Comment: And you don't have a firewall running on the server at all?

Comment: i dont think so. my port is open according this tool: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: can you try run the Client.java file on your own computer and i will know if it can connect (my server open)

Comment: People should not be asking unknown parties to connect to their internal machines like this.  Rife with security problems.

Comment: ok sorry for asking. acctually someone did connect to me and write some things

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, set up a static IP (like `192.168.1.6`) internally.

If youu want to connect via an external IP, there are two ways:

1. If you have a router, use port forwarding.
2. If you have a dongle, no need to port forward; you can directly access the server. Just give the dongle's external IP (to find that, use a what's-my-IP service like [this one](https://www.whatismyip.com/)) and a port number (any). (Dongles are not blocked by any ISP.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your internal IP address along with your server name to /etc/hosts, for example, if you have external IP 10. 10. 123. 123, and with the server name YOURCOMPUTER_1.XXX.XXX, you want to connect inside network, you can add:

127.0.0.1 YOURCOMPUTER_1.XXX.XXX to your /etc/hosts