# Java : How to connect to ServerSocket using router public IP?

Tags: java, sockets, portforwarding

I'm trying to connect to server socket in java using my router's public ip,

first, I tried by simply configuring server socket to localhost, like this,

```
server = new ServerSocket(5000);
```

It is working on localhost but not working on trying internal ip 192.168.1.6
then, I tried configuring server socket to the internal Ip (saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420237/why-socket-does-not-connect-with-ip-instead-of-localhost)), code is as follows,

```
int backlog = 5;
server = new ServerSocket(5000, backlog, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.6"));
```

and it is working as my devices are connected to same network, I can connect to this Ip 192.168.1.6 from a device with Ip 192.168.1.5 on the same network but when I use public ip of my router from client side, connection is getting timed out, I've done port forwarding,
[image: screenshot of port forwarding]

What am I doing wrong here? any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT :
I came to about NAT-loopback (saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835982/make-a-connection-using-an-external-ip-address-in-java)) as I was trying to connect using public ip while being on same network so I tried different network but still it is not connecting, connection is getting timed out.

Comment: I think that you can fix your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835982/make-a-connection-using-an-external-ip-address-in-java)

Comment: I don't think this is a java issue

Comment: thanks, baggio, I just came to know about NAT-loopback, and also saw this comment "If you are still inside LAN (as i understand) you have to use internal IP. If you are on the same computer, you have to use 127.0.0.1" and as I was trying to connect using public ip on same network so I tried different network but still it is not connecting.

Comment: You don't connect to sockets. You connect to ports. You have to open the port at the public side of the router, and you have to arrange port forwarding from there to the internal port to which your `ServerSocket` is bound.

Comment: @user207421, in the port forwarding screenshot, ive done the same, and it is working for other apis like spring or node js, im able to call these apis from different network but with ServerSocket, connection is getting timed out.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly replace your port number by 8080, which is the default port for HTTP when you are not root. Then you have to open the port 8080 on your router to allow the client to connect.
Your server must be connected to the Internet and have a public IP address. Then the client can connect to this public IP address.

Comment: in the port forwarding screenshot, ive done the same, and it is working for other apis like spring or node js, where http requests are made. but in socket this mustn't be http right.?